# Scala / Play / Joda - No Json Serializer found for type (String, org.joda.time.DateTime)

Tags: json, scala, playframework, jodatime

I am trying to serialise a (String, DateTime), but I am running into an error. I understand there is a more up-to-date `play.libs.json.jodaReads / .jodaWrites`, but I currently have to use the method I show below.

How do I properly define a reads/writes/format for joda DateTime?

```
import play.api.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.libs.json._
import org.joda.time.DateTime
```

**Repository**

```
def dateTimeCall(id: String): Future[(String, DateTime)] = {

    implicit val jodaDateReads = Reads.jodaDateReads("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'")
    implicit val jodaDateWrites = Writes.jodaDateWrites("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'")
    implicit val dateFormat: Format[DateTime] = Format(jodaDateReads, jodaDateWrites)
    implicit val dateTimeFormat: Format[(String, DateTime)] = Json.format[(String, DateTime)]

    val result: Future[(String, DateTime)] = getDateTime(id)
    result

}
```

**Controller**

```
def dateTimeController(/* -- ommitted --*/) {
    val id = "..."
    repository.getDateTime(id).map {
        result =>
            Ok(serialize(result))
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
No Json serializer found for type (String, org.joda.time.DateTime). Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
[error]                             Ok(serialize(result))
[error]                                         ^
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot migrate to Java time (recommended), you can derived joda codec from those for Java time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define Json Readers and Writers outside of your method, probably in some object. Then import it. Otherwise your implicits are invisible. In this case in Controller you should have those as imported or you can define inside body